# What is the difference between running node-daemon and pm2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, daemon, pm2

I would like to run node.js script in the background forever. I found 2 options. Node-daemon and pm2. I think both can achieve the goal of running a node.js process in the background. What are the differences between these 2 ways of running node.js processes in the background?

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-daemon

Comment: PM2 is more widely used (10k Github stars vs 2)  and more active (released 6 days ago vs a year ago). PM2 is relatively complicated. If you need something simple [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) (and probably other libraries)  could also help.

Comment: apart from serious memory consumption  issues  pm2 . very clean , precise and developer friendly nodejs deployment module